# Raising automatically hierarchical levels of section

Tags: sectioning

I have a document with this structure :

```
\begin{document}
\section{One}
\subsection{a}
\subsection{b}
\subsection{c}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to automatically transform it into this :

```
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\section{a}
\section{b}
\section{c}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: find and replace '\section' with '\chapter' after that 'sub' with ''.

Comment: most editors would let you edit all the files in a collection with just a few keystrokes, otherwise you can do `\let\subsection\section\let\section\chapter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search-replace `\section{` with `\chapter{`, `\subsection{` with `\section{` etc.

Comment: Yep, I thought about it but for long documents with several files it can be tedious so I dreamed about a programmatic way of doing this

Answer (score 3):

The `memoir` class (a superset of `book`, `report` and `article`) has the divisional hierarchy of `\chapter`, `\section` etc (plus some higher ones). If the `article` option is used then `\chapter` is treated like an `article \section`, `\section` is treated like `article \subsection` and so on.

This means that you can switch between `book` and `article` style output just by changing the class options.

I realise that this doesn't answer your question but it might be something to bear in mind for any future documents.

Comment: extremely useful!

Answer (score 3):

By adding

```
\let\subsubsection\subsection
\let\subsection\section
\let\section\chapter
```

to your preamble it will redefine section to be a chapter.
Be sure to do this in the correct order, otherwise every sectioning command will generate a chapter.

This has the downside of not being clear to read in the code itself, whereas the search-replace option allows you to use the same method form this answer to "go back" and not use chapters.

Comment: thanks @David Carlisle, this is indeed quicker to implement.